# Error message where user don`t exist, php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build an web application. When the user try to log in, and the email dont exist or the password is incorrect it stay to index page.What I want is that when the email dont exist or when the password is incorrect to stay in index page, and to display an message:"Email dont exist" in this page...I have tried o lot of things, but nothing function till now...My code is below:

```
   <?php 

    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die("Smund te lidhet me serverin");
    mysql_select_db("axhenda") or die("Kjo databaze nuk u gjet");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {//kontrollo per  butonin submit
    $Email=$_POST['email'];//variable ang $Username kag ang $_POST['UserName'] ay value sang textbox nga UserName
    $Fjalekalimi=$_POST['pass'];//variable ang $Username kag ang $_POST['Password'] ay value sang textbox nga Password


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM perdoruesi where Emaili = '$Email' AND  Fjalekalimi = '$Fjalekalimi'") or die("Kjo query nuk mund te plotesohet");

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);//isipon kn may tyakto sa query
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);//ma return row sa database

            if ($count > 0){//kun may tyakto sa query e execute yah ang code sa dalom
            session_start();//para mag start ang session
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['Id_Per'];//kwaon ang id sang may tyakto nga username kag password ang ibotang sa $_SESSION['member_id']
            header('location:home.php');
            }
else{
            header('location:index.html');
            }
    }
```

What should I put at this part to display the error message

```
else{
            header('location:index.html');
            }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and inform yourself about SQL-injections and prepared statements before you continue your work.

Comment: But no...I have tried this...but it does not display nothing..because when i press submit, the index page just reloads... I am thinking to put a label at index page and make it dispay:none, and at the sigin.php page make it document.getElementById('labelid').style.display = 'block'....but I am afraid that it will not recognize labelid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your condition:**

```
if ($count > 0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['Id_Per'];
    header('location:home.php');
}else{
    header('location:index.php?error=404');
}
```

**then in index.php**

```
if($_GET['error']==404){
    echo "Email does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change index.html to index.php and then redirect them to something like index.php?error=1
Inside index.php, I would check if isset($_GET['error']) and if($_GET['error'] == 1, you can output an error. My easy way though.

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable with the error message. Then redirect to **index.php** and there, check to see if the session variable is set. If so, display the error message and clear the session variable.